# Best way to communicate between Spring applications within same JVM

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, ejb

I am looking for any idea which is Spring equivalent to EJB with local interface. I want to communicate between webapps within one application server (Tomcat), obtain something like direct-call across applications.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try JMS for commucation between apps: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/

Answer (score 2):

The best way depends on your requirements.
For two webapps in a same JVM, I don't think that you have standard for that.

Note that in any cases, an EJB container provides features to communicate between two applications hosted in a same server that you could probably not get out of the box by other technologies (pooling, transaction, and so for...).

1) RMI, a component oriented, close to the EJBs but low level technology

Indeed, technically speaking RMI is close to the EJB technology that relies itself on the RMI technology (among other things).
But RMI is also a low level API, so you should rewrite many features provided out of the box by EJBs (pooling, transaction, and so for...).

2) REST, a service and interoperability oriented technology

Today these webapps are hosted on the same Tomcat instance.
Tomorrow, for multiple reasons (too much loading, cloud and so for...) these could be deployed on distinct JVMs.
Using higher abstraction than JVM and a more standard way to communicate between app such as HTTP REST may be a good thing.

Comment: RMI oh my! :) Is anyone using it? JMS though would be a much more suited advice...

Comment: @Eugene Not a lot I think :)  Technically speaking, RMI is closer to the EJB technology that the JMS API is as EJB is based (among other things) on RMI.  After as a general question on how to communicate between two applications, I would use REST. And if REST was not possible I would indeed use JMS.